# Date and Time column in R

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

I am stuck on a column with both date and time in it.

My column looks like this:

```
Date.Rept
12/1/2016
12/1/2013 12:07 AM
12/1/2016  7:76 AM 
12/1/2016 11:54 AM
12/2/2016  1:34 PM
```

My goal is to separate the date and time into two separate columns.

I first changed everything in the data frame to `as.character`, then used the below code to get just the date within that column.

How do I extract the time into a separate column, so that I have two columns one with just data and the other with time?

Code  used: `crime$Date.Rept <- as.Date(crime$Date.Rept, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")`

Result: `2016-12-01`

Comment: What's `7:76 AM` ?

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `extract` from `tidyr` to separate into two columns by capture one or more non-white space characters as a group (`(\\S+)`) followed by zero or more spaces (`\\s*`) followed by any characters as a second capture group (`(.*)`)

```
library(tidyr)
extract(crime, Date.Rept, into = c("Date", "Time"), "(\\S+)\\s*(.*)")
#       Date     Time
#1 12/1/2016         
#2 12/1/2013 12:07 AM
#3 12/1/2016  7:76 AM
#4 12/1/2016 11:54 AM
#5 12/2/2016  1:34 PM
```

---

Or another option is `sub/read.csv` from `base R`

```
read.csv(text=sub("\\s+", ",", crime$Date.Rept), header=FALSE, 
           col.names = c("Date", "Time"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
#       Date     Time
#1 12/1/2016         
#2 12/1/2013 12:07 AM
#3 12/1/2016  7:76 AM
#4 12/1/2016 11:54 AM
#5 12/2/2016  1:34 PM
```

Comment: That worked great! Thank you. Now just for my own knowledge, I get the extract part but... we basically said separate on the first white space and any subsequent white space stays in the second capture group?

Comment: @sabih4911  The first one with `extract` captures the non-white space characters in the 'Date' then matches any space and the second group captures all other characters if present.  Similarly, in the second case, we replace the first space with `,` and use `read.csv` to read it as two columns with `,` as delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

By looking at your code it seem like you are actually trying to convert to `Date` and `Time` classes (you've used `as.Date`), base R doesn't have a `Time` class, but you could try `data.table` for that. I'm adding a pre-step in order to handle values with missing time (and I have no idea what time is `7:76`) but the resulting columns are easy to manipulate (add/subscribe/filter/etc.)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(crime)[nchar(as.character(Date.Rept)) < 18, Date.Rept := paste(Date.Rept, "12:00 AM")]
crime[, c("Date", "Time") := IDateTime(as.POSIXct(Date.Rept, format = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"))]
crime
#            Date.Rept       Date     Time
# 1: 12/1/2016 12:00 AM 2016-12-01 00:00:00
# 2: 12/1/2013 12:07 AM 2013-12-01 00:07:00
# 3: 12/1/2016  7:76 AM       <NA>     <NA>
# 4: 12/1/2016 11:54 AM 2016-12-01 11:54:00
# 5: 12/2/2016  1:34 PM 2016-12-02 13:34:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
It looks like your data might be a good candidate for strsplit().  This option will require some additional work since this strsplit() function will produce a list of the split vector values.

```
crime2 <- strsplit(crime$Date.Rept, " ")
```

Option 2: My personal preference would be to split your data using the tidyr() package.

```
crime2 <- separate(crime, Date.Rept, c("date.value", "time.value"), sep = " ")
```

This will create a data frame that will then need to be appended back to the original file.  You can easily accomplish this by the following.

```
crime3 <- cbind(crime,crime2)
```

For any additional date manipulation or comparisons, you might considering using the lubridate() package.  I have found this package is much easier to use than the base r date tools.